# Google Calendar Push Notification: 'reason' : 'notFound'

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I want to setup a push notification for the user's `calendarID` per the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891257/google-push-notification-giving-parseerror).

```
@blueprint.route("/notifications", methods={'GET','POST'})
def timeBlocker():
    email = request.json.get('email')
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    acessToken = accessToken(email, user.refresh)
    body = {
        'id': '01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab', 
        'type': 'web_hook',
        'address': 'https://<registeredDomain>/notifications'
    }
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
    calendarID = '...@group.calendar.google.com'
    req = requests.post(url=f'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarID}@group.calendar.google.com/events/watch', data = json.dumps(body), headers=headers) 
    return str(req.json())
```

However, I keep on getting:

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'Not Found'}], 'code': 404, 'message': 'Not Found'}}
```

which isn't meaningful. At the same time, the [doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#example) gives such code as an example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json
```

with *my_calendar@gmail.com* taken a calendarID when in reality the calendarIDs I've been receiving all end with *@group.calendar.google.com*. Thus, I am not sure if this is causing the case but keen to know how I shall fix the error.

Comment: What line gives you the 404?

Comment: `return str(req.json())`

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `requests.post()` line? Is this on your calendar, or another user's calendar?